# Format: "{0:n0}" is not working if I use rowTemplate in kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

If I use rowTemplate in Grid, number format is not working.

If I comment rowTemplate line numberformat is working fine..is there any relation b/w rowTemplate and format: `{0,n0}`?
Here I'm using row template for getting property values from database.

```
<script id="SellTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${Fore}
        </td>           
        <td align="Left">    
            <img src="/Images/${ Indicator }.png"  width="20" height="20" />          
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

$("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    width: 1500,
    dataSource: data.d,
    resizable: true,
    rowTemplate:kendo.template($("#SellTemplate").html()),;
    kendo.template($("#SellTemplate").html()),
    height: 750,                                
    selectable: true,
    columns: [
        { title: 'Fore', field: 'Fore', width: '12%', format: "{0:n0}", sortable: true },
        { title: 'Indicator', field: 'Indicator', width: '4%', sortable: true},
    ]
});
```

Comment: can you suggest,how can i achieve.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `rowTemplate` you are in full control of the grid row rendering. The built-in row template is overridden by the custom one. You can still format values though - use the [kendo.format](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#format) function in your template:

```
    <td>
        ${kendo.format("{0:n0}", Fore)}
    </td>
```